# authorisation and login control in an Angular app

Tags: angularjs, cookies, authentication, authorization

So for the past few months I have been developing the 'login functionality' of my Angular apps like this. The user logs in and if the credentials are correct, the REST API returns a token. I take that token and store it as a cookie:

```
$cookies.put('authorisation', data['token']);
```

Whenever I call the $http service, I submit the authorisation cookie as a header and it authorises the http request. Then on the controller of each view I add:

```
if (!$cookies.get('authorisation')) {
    $location.path('/login');
}
```

So if the cookie doesn't exist, the user is automatically kicked to the login screen.

This has worked for me just fine up until now but I can't help but feel that it is not the 'correct' way of doing things. Could anyone shed a little light on what the best practice method for this could be? And perhaps why what I'm doing is 'wrong'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with Angular $http Interceptors:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

You could use the request interceptor to have your authorization checked before each $http request.

If you do this you also have to integrate a custom Flag on each $http config object (e.g. skipAuthorization) in order to allow the user to perform Requests without being logged in (useful for actually logging in ;-))

---

@AzzyDude to your comment: 
I'm using ui-router to do the navigation inside of my Angular 1.6.X Application. 
You can either integrate own config-properties on the states (isGuestState) or if its a closed application such as mine, hard-coded in a $stateChange event, like this:
[image]

Comment: Okay, yeah, I have heard of interceptors before. I can look into this further. But then how exactly should one restrict access to pages when the user is not logged in? Should it just be if $http fails, bounce back to login?

Comment: Hi @AzzyDude, if its still of interest, i added my $stateChangeStart EventHandler in the Answer

Comment: Many thanks for getting back to me on that, even 2 years later! :)